# How do you run shell scripts in postgres container to determine if the database is empty, and import a backup SQL script if it is not

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, docker, docker-compose

I want to migrate my project to vagrant vm, part of this is migrating database data to vagrant, I use the postgres container to hold the data, So I mounted a directory into `/var/lib.postgresql/` and the backup SQL script into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` for automatic loading of backup data and data persistence.

```
docker run --name test1 -v /postgresShellTest/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ -v /postData/:/var/lib/postgresql/ postgres:11.4
```

However, this causes the added data to be deleted by the backup SQL each time the container is created after it has been deleted. While it is possible to `not mount the backup SQL later`, this is not very convenient. So I wonder if I can add the judgment that if there is a table of the project, the backup SQL will not be run, otherwise the database will be initialized.

I mount a shell.sh to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`, content as follows

```
BAK=/var/lib/postgresql/data/
if [ "`ls -A ${BAK}`" = "" ];
then 
    echo "${BAK} is empty"
    psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres < edgeai.sql
else
    echo "${BAK} is not empty"
fi
```

because For the first time mounted an empty folder to `/var/lib/postgresql/data/`, But this psql report: `could not connect to server: No such file or directory ....socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

So I want to psql search table

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -c 'SELECT * FROM mytable'
```

but error reported `psql: FATAL:  database "SELECT * FROM my_table" does not exist`

I didn't know how else to accomplish my goals

I would very appreciate it if you guys can tell me how to achieve it

Comment: your database name is "postgres" ?

Comment: No, I'm just testing to see if it works.The project use sa database of other names.I tried to run the backup SQL directly and it still executed, as if the backup load had nothing to do with the database name